# Validating Credit Card Data With Stripe Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, coffeescript, stripe-payments

In Rails, I'm working on integrating Stripe into a project I'm working on. As it is a membership site, I need to collect cc data when a user makes an account. I've already installed the stripe gem and added the keys.

I have the following fields on **devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "number", class: "form-control"} %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= label_tag :card_code, "CVC" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc", class: "form-control"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag nil, "Expiration Date" %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true }, {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-month", class: "form-control"} %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10 },  {:name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-year", class: "form-control"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Next, I need to validate these fields on submission of the form. I was directed to do this with javascript, so I created a new file **registrations.js.coffee**:

```
jQuery ->
Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
payment.setupForm()

payment = 
    setupForm: ->
        $('#new_registration').submit ->
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
            Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_registration'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
            false


    handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
        if status == 200
            alert(response.id)
        else
            alert(response.error.message)
```

When I submit this form on localhost, I get the error message: **SyntaxError: [stdin]:14:5: unexpected if
  (in c:/Users/Bill/Desktop/testapp/app/assets/javascripts/registrations.js.coffee)**

This line of code is highlighted:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Actual indent of coffee:

[image]

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript? Are you mixing spaces and tabs in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: I believe I have the indenting correct, I've attached a screenshot of the code exactly as it looks in the app.

Comment: Note the alignment of the `if` and the `alert` under it in your screenshot and in your question. Rewrite `handleStripeResponse` and be careful that your indentation is consistent and exactly what it should be. Indentation is all you have to structure your code in CoffeeScript so you must get it exactly right.

Comment: Thanks, that stopped the error from occurring. Though the code doesn't actually appear to be validating the cc fields. I'll have to look into this further.